# list.appendChild(TOCEntry) shows type Error: its not a function

Tags: javascript

```
function createTOC(){

    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    var headingText;
    var TOCEntry;
    var i;
    for( i=1; i<=10; i++){
        headingText = document.getElementById(i);
        TOCEntry = document.createElement("li");
        TOCEntry = "<a href=#" + i + ">" + headingText + "</a>";
        list.appendChild(TOCEntry);
    }
}
```

`list.appendChild(TOCEntry)` shows type Error: its not a function.

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.
First, create a dom element
then assign its innerHTML
then add it to Dom

```
  function createTOC(){

    var list = document.getElementById("id of ul");
    var headingText;
    var TOCEntry;
    var i;
    for( i=1; i<=10; i++){
       headingText = document.getElementById(i);
       TOCEntry = document.createElement("li");
       TOCEntryData = "<a href=#" + i + ">" + headingText + "</a>";
       TOCEntry.innerHtml = TOCEntryData;
       list.appendChild(TOCEntry);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @KrunalPatel If you want to append it to single ul that you can use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0):

function createTOC(){

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var headingText;
var TOCEntry;

    var i;
for( i=1; i<=10; i++){
   headingText = document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
   TOCEntry = document.createElement("li");
   TOCEntryData = "<a href=#" + i + ">" + headingText + "</a>";
   TOCEntry.innerHTML = TOCEntryData;
  list.appendChild(TOCEntry);


}
```

}